# Is an infinite dimensional vector space complete under the norm $\|x\|=\sum|x_i|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Suppose $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a Hamel basis of infinite dimensional vector space $X$.

Define the norm $\|x\|=\sum|x_i|$ where $x=\sum x_ie_i$.

Is this normed space complete?

Answer (score 2):

The space is not complete.  Without loss of generality, suppose that $\Bbb N \subset I$. It suffices to show that the sequence
$$
x^{(n)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i} e_i
$$
is Cauchy, but non-convergent.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not complete. For example consider the space of the definitely null sequences:
$$
X=\{x:=(x_n)\;|\;\exists N\in\mathbb N: x_m=0\;\forall m\geq N\}.
$$
This is an infinite-dimensional space. In this case, you can take
$$
e_1=(1,0,0,0\ldots),\quad e_2=(0,1,0,0\ldots),\quad \ldots
$$
Consider the sequence $x^k$ defined by
$$
(x^k)_n=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
2^{-n},\quad \textrm{if }n\leq k\\
0 \quad \textrm{if }n> k.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This is a Cauchy sequence in the norm $\|\cdot\|$, but its limit is not in $X$. In fact, its limit cannot be anything else but the sequence $\bar x$, with 
$$
(\bar x)_n= 2^{-n}
$$
and, of course, $\bar x\not\in X$.