# Are there incomplete normed spaces of arbitrary size?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

For every infinite cardinal, there is a vector space whose dimension is that cardinal. Is the situation the same for incomplete normed spaces? Can we have algebraic dimension of arbitrary size?

Comment: Perhaps use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916867/is-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space-complete-under-the-norm-x-sumx-i?rq=1).

Comment: @DavidMitra That's a very neat answer

Comment: @Alek Every finite-dimensional normed vector space is complete; perhaps you meant to ask about every *infinite* cardinal.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, I'll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean real or complex spaces, and by "incomplete" you mean "not necessarily complete" (if you really mean "not complete", then the answer is the same, except there are no finite-dimensional examples).

I will consider real vector spaces for simplicity. Choose any cardinal $\kappa$. Then let $V=c_c(\kappa)$, the space of finitely supported functions $\kappa\to \mathbf R$. It is easy to see that this space has dimenson $\kappa$.

You can make it a normed space in any number of ways, and most of them will be incomplete (in fact, for quite a few $\kappa$, *all* of them will be incomplete). For example, if you endow it with the $\ell^p$ norm for any $p\in[1,\infty)$, it is easy to see that the completion of $V$ is $\ell^p(\kappa)\neq V$.